# Why does LLVM projects use GCC Headers

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang

I am looking at a project that is built with Clang but it needs GCC headers.

Why would a project require both Clang and GCC headers?

Comment: That would depend on the project and the decisions of the project authors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, clang builds with the standard library installed on the system, so objects can be linked with libraries/programs built by other compilers. If you have installed libc++, you can use it with the flag `-stdlib=libc++`.

For more information have a look at the [documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html).